# Cross platform git developement on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, git, version-control, cross-platform

I'm developing a project on Windows and Linux - both OSes are installed on the same box, in a dual-boot, dual-partition configuration (Windows on NTFS, Linux on ext4).

I'm using git (and github) and want to share the work between Windows and Linux world. At first, I thought it was as simple as using the exact same local repository from both OSes - e.g., by mounting the NTFS partition in Linux and directly working the same repo.

This approach quickly ran into issues however. For example, NTFS doesn't support UNIX permissions and I also had CRLF issues. Some quick reading seems to indicate that direct sharing of a single git repo like this doesn't work well for cross-plat development (at least when one platform is Windows, and one is UNIX-like).

So what are my options for working locally across both OSes? I am often working offline, so don't want to rely on any solution that requires internet access (so, for example, solutions that require github as an intermediary are out).

Comment: What is the problem with `git clone ...` in each OS?

Comment: That's a possible solution, but then how to share work-in-progress between the OSes? I want to make some changes in Linux, then flip over to Windows, compile and test them, for example.

Comment: Here is something that may help you beat CRLF issue https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/ please take a look.

Comment: @BeeOnRope did you flesh out your approach and could share some lessons learned or best practices? Just set up a dual boot of Windows and Pop!_OS and thinking about a similar setup, but ran into the problem of Linux not recognizing my existing git repos on the NTFS drive

Comment: @Rappster - basically I have separate repos on the Linux and Windows side (i.e., clones of the same project), and then use the normal push and pull mechanisms to share changes, using github as an intermediary, or sometimes directly between the projects themselves (you can set a local project as a remote), e.g., mounting the windows partition in Linux.